# CSV - Unique Combinations of Column Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have what I think is probably not a very unique problem.

I have an application where a user can upload a CSV. I would like to validate that CSV against data already in the database based off of the values of three of the fields in the CSV.

Imagine I have a CSV with five columns: Stuff 1, Stuff 2, Stuff 3, Stuff 4, Stuff 5.

I need to find all the unique combinations that exist for Stuff 1, Stuff 3, and Stuff 4 in the CSV so that I can run a query against the database to see if there are records with those combinations that already exist.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Here is what I have for my CSV object.

```
CSV::HeaderConverters[:mystrip] = lambda{|s| s.strip}
@csv = CSV.readlines(@import_file.path, header_converters: [:mystrip] , headers: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combinations = @csv.map {|row| [row[0], row[2], row[3]]}.uniq

combinations.each do |values|
  if Model.where(value_1: values[0], value_2: values[1], value_3: values[2]).exists?
    # Stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: To add on to this how could I use those results which would be an array of arrays with an AR query. I would need to do something like Model.where("value_1 (?) & value_2 (?)"row[0], row[2], row[3]).

Comment: Added an example ActiveRecord query.